# Show that any vector can be written as a sum of a vector mapped to zero and a constant multiple of a fixed vector

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm solving exercises from a linear algebra book, and am now having trouble with the following exercise:

> Let $V$ be a vector space and $F: V \rightarrow\Bbb R$ a linear map.
> Let $W \ne V$ be the subset of $V$ consisting of all elements $v$ such that $F(v) = 0$. Let $v_0$ be an element of $V$ not in $W$.
>
> Show that every element of V can be wrriten as a sum $w + cv_0$, with some $w$ in W and some number $c$.

What I tried:

Since this map maps into $\Bbb R$, $F(v) = cF(v_0)$ for some $c$.
$F(v) = cF(v_0)$ => $F(v) = cF(v_0) + 0$ => $F(v) = cF(v_0) + F(w)$ for some $w$ in $W$ => $F(v) = F(cv_0 + w)$.

Using the basic properties of linear maps, I got that far, but that doesn't really help since the linear map isn't necessarily injective.

Any hints would be grealy appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea: $F(v_0)\neq 0$ because $v_0\not\in W$, so for any $v\in V$ there is a constant $c$ such that $F(v)=cF(v_0)$.

Since $F$ is linear, this can be rewritten as $F(v-cv_0)=0$. Now what can be said about $v-cv_0$?

Comment: It means it's in $W$! And that $v - cv_0 = w$ for some $W$ :) Thanks

Comment: Exactly, happy to help